# How can I check if a value exists in a list of elements with XPath?

Tags: java, xpath

Given a list like this:

```
<MyObjectListWrapper>
    <list>
        <object>
          <name>PAUL</name>
        </object>
        <object>
          <name>ROBERT</name>
        </object>
        <object>
          <name>ANDY</name>
        </object>
        <object>
          <name>ALAN</name>
        </object>
    </list>
<MyObjectListWrapper>
```

How can you check if "ANDY" exists when you don't know where it is in the list of objects?

Comment: You want to try to access a `name` tag which contains the 'ANDY' text : `/MyObjectListWrapper/list/object/name[text() == "ANDY"]`. If it returns the empty set ANDY isn't in your list, otherwise it is.

Comment: @Aaron there is no xpath operator such `==`.

Comment: Thank you @dafie. Your comment would be even more useful if it mentionned that the operator I was obviously looking for is `=`.

Comment: `//name="ANDY"` is just enough (returns boolean TRUE/FALSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search for any name that equals your search term as suggested.

```
//name="ANDY"
```

This is even XPath 1.0 compatible.  [Online Demo](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/3lE78L6OQ)
[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/vBNS6r)